# Error :The security token included in the request is invalid.Response Status Code: ForbiddenError Code: InvalidClientTokenIdError

Tags: c#, web-services, amazon-sns

we designed the WebService application in vs 2010 using AWS SDK toolkit which connect to AWS SNS Service.

It Perfectly works when we directly run from VS 2010 Development studio, but when we publish webservice to Local IIS or dedicated webserver it fails to create topic with following error Messages.

The security token included in the request is invalid.Response Status Code: ForbiddenError Code: InvalidClientTokenIdError

Actually i didn't get how to get security token and where to put the security token in my web application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to run AWS SNS application from local IIS and or existing web service.

if you want to run your web service application on server for outside access, you need to 
-Create a profile
-Create an IAM Role for that profile
-Launch an EC2 Instance and Specify the IAM Role.